# How to find basis of following space in the problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $a = \begin{pmatrix}3 \\2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},$ $b=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix},$ $c=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix},$  $d=\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\0\\2\end{pmatrix},$ $e=\begin{pmatrix}2\\2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ $f=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $a,b$,and $c$ is denoted by $V$, and subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ spanned by $d,e$ and $f$ is denoted by $W$

Now suppose the set of vectors which belong to both $V$ and $W$ is denoted by $Z.$ How to find a basis for $Z$.

I tried to take the differences $a-d, b-e$ and $c-f$ but that is not working. What should I do?

Comment: You should first figure out exactly what subspace $Z$ is, and then find a basis that is otherwise unrelated to $a,b,c,d,e$ or $f$.

Comment: how to figure out that? i tried it but couldn't find a way

Comment: Take an element in $Z$, you can write it as a linear combination of $a,b,c$ and as a linear combination of $d,e,f$. Put those two equal to each other, this gives you a system of equations that you can solve, which describes $Z$. Then find a basis of $Z$.

Comment: but it says union..it doesn't says that they are equal.... different elements of V and W can also lie in Z

Comment: It is unclear from your question that $Z = V \cup W$

Comment: If we say the set of vectors which belong to both V and W is denoted by Z then doesn't that mean Z is a union of V and W?

Comment: @saqib No. The set of vectors that is in *both* $V$ and $W$ is their intersection $V\cap W$. The set of vectors that’s in *either* $V$ or $W$ is the union, which in general isn’t even a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Let $span( (3,2,1,0),(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0))=V$ and $ span((3,2,0,2),(2,2,0,1),(1,1,0,1))=W$. 
Then  $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0) \in V$. Thus the above list is a basis of V. Also $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,1) \in W$. It then immediately follows that $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\in V \cup W$ since this list is linearly independent and a basis of $V\cup W$ that then follows that $V\cup W = \Re^4$. To get the basis of V or of W just add a linear combination of the given vectors then it should follow. If you mean the intersection of V and W then it should easily be deduced that $(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0)$ is a basis.

Comment: If you need the direct calculations I can post them later today when I have the chance.

Comment: How will we do it for intersection of W and V